# OOP JavaScript - this reference

Tags: javascript, oop, this

For some strange reason, when calling a function that assigns `this` to `thisObj`, I get an error:

> TypeError: thisObj is undefined

Here's what I've got:

```
function templateObject() 
{
    "use strict";
    var thisObj = this;

    function _loadBackgroundImages() 
    {
        "use strict";
        // something happens here
    }


    thisObj.initialise = function() 
    {
        "use strict";
        _loadBackgroundImages();
    };
}
```

The function is then called using the instantiation like so:

```
var templateObj = templateObject();
templateObj.initialise();
```

Can't figure out why I get the error - any idea?

Comment: You haven't posted any code that refers to either `this` or your variable "thisObj". It would also be helpful (well, extremely important) to see how you're calling "templateObject". (*edit* Doh!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well - it is thisObj.initialise call

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry.  However, it all depends on how you call the "templateObject" function.

Comment: The value of `this` depend on how you call a function. You haven't shown us how you call `templateObject`. (I can probably guess how, and why that causes the problem, but it would nice to work with what you actually have instead of what I assume you have).

Comment: [May I suggest some light reading over at MDN?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Fthis)

Comment: Just updated the question with how it is actually called.

Comment: I know, but I'm not really calling 'this' from within this private function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

```
var templateObj = new templateObject();
```

Calling function with `new` will pass newly created empty object as `this` to the function and then return it to `templateObj`.

Comment: Of course - how could I miss that! Thanks @mishik - appreciate it!

Comment: Another option is to handle the check inside of your function. You can have a `if(!(this instanceof templateObject)) return new templateObject();` and then you wouldn't necessarily need to use `new`. You still SHOULD, though, so it may be a bad idea to build that crutch in.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function like you've done (i.e. not as a method of an object):

```
templateObject()
```

Then, if you’re in strict mode, `this` will be undefined inside that function.

[As @mishik pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17928196/20578), it looks like you wanted `templateObject` to be a constructor function, and to use it as such, you need to call it with the `new` keyword before it:

```
var templateObj = new templateObject();
```

One style note: it's conventional in JavaScript to name functions intended to be used as constructors with an initial capital.

That might make mistakes like this marginally less likely, as it'd look odd to see a function with an initial capital called without `new`:

```
function TemplateObject() {
    ...
}
var templateObj = new TemplateObject();
```

Comment: Javascript strict mode modifies the behavior of the `this` keyword. In strict mode it will not expose the global object. That's why the example reference is `undefined`.

Comment: @Bart: Indeedio, although I think in this case you get the same error with or without `"use strict";`? (I'm not 100% on that, but that's the behaviour I got when I tried it.)

Comment: The `this` keyword, without strict mode, is *always* an object. I found [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) wich explains the behavior.

Comment: It seem to be working fine however with the strict mode and the scenario I have in the question.

Comment: @Bart: aha, yes I see. I tried it without `"use strict"` on JSFiddle, but I think maybe something else was setting use strict, as when I [tried it in isolation](http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/17928103/), removing `"use strict";` made the error go away.